# What is the graphql Introspection query?

Tags: graphql, graphene-python

What is the graphql Introspection query.i am trying to this toll.it's work but i don't know what's the meaning of graphql Introspection query.

[I am trying this tool](http://nathanrandal.com/graphql-visualizer/)

Comment: Take a look at http://graphql.org/learn/introspection/ that should give you a basic understanding. The specific tool you looked at helps with visualizing the datamodel of the graphql api. Basically introspection is used for "intellisense" in GraphiQL and meant as a means to "selfdocumentation". Another more interactive tool for visualizing the introspection is https://apis.guru/graphql-voyager/ (my personal favorite)

Comment: thanks.good comment.

Answer (score 4):

[Per the spec](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/#sec-Introspection), compliant GraphQL server implementations expose a special query that describes the schema itself.  This allows for clients like [Graphiql](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql) to be able to accomplish things like type-ahead and auto completion of queries.

Comment: thanks. i am try this tool  >> http://nathanrandal.com/graphql-visualizer/  for visualize my project schema.